# during change of IP address - adware infection

Tags: malware

I have a puzzling situation. I have build a small site for a friend which I am hosting together with other site I have. His domain is registered with a certain company which is also an ISP provider.

During the redirection of his domain to the site (this is with hostgator) I tested the site and instead of the site I got an adware type looking website. Also the Laptop I viewed the website with was diagnosed after that as being infected with adware. The funny thing was that the site could be seen fine from other parts of the world even from where I am if I used a different ISP (y viewed on my phone via my phone network) or through a proxy. But I was always redirected to an adware site if I viewed it using the company in question (one with whom the domain was registered with also the ISP provider).

I have cleaned my PC and now the site can be accessed just fine. I also run an anti-virus check on my site and it was all clear.

Also my friend was also infected with an adware while he must have browsed the webpage to check for the redirection being done. So now when he tries to go to the site he gets redirected to some page with ads.

So my question is: Is it possible that the ISP was infected and (1) that infection affected the domains that go via their proxy? or (2) that affected only the site whose IP redirection was in progress. Maybe while the IP address propagation was taking place - and while we requested the site - an adware could have sneaked in?

I am puzzled by the whole thing.

Is anyone familiar with what I am describing? Sorry if this sounds puzzling.

Thank you
Amelia

Comment: This could also be caused by malware on your PC that intercepted the web request. If the problem disappeared after cleaning your PC, this gives some confirmation of this hypothesis. Do you have some logs of the cleaner that you used?

Answer (score 1):

Your ISP cache DNS redirected you to a different IP, most probably its a new website and it takes certain time to refresh DNS records on any DNS server depending on their configuration and DNS TTL as well as on your laptop OS.

Comment: when situations reoccurs you can type command`nslookup yoursite.com <DNS Server IP>`  Where yoursite.com is site having issue and DNS server IP is your ISP DNS server IP. Example  : nslookup google.com 8.8.8.8